# HTML text form value

Tags: text, input

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="n"tee">
```

Is there any way to show n"tee in the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use special char:

```
&quot;
```

and your code will be:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="n&quot;tee">
```

The double quote (`"`) has special meaning inside a HTML attribute. If you want to put it into an input value, you must (this is not a true must but a good rule of thumb) write it as its entity `&quot;`. There is no way around it.

Comment: @JasperJye yes, i checked it and i'm wrong, i'll edit the answer in just a sec